# Why can't I parse this json data in Google Chrome console

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-devtools

I type this in chrome console

```
    var data = [
{
    "name":"john doe",
    "birth":"09/07/15"
},
{
    "name":"jane doe",
    "birth":"09/07/15"
}
];

JSON.parse([data[0]);
```

but I got error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
>       at Object.parse (native)

why ?

Comment: because it's already parsed (the code is delivered as an object literal instead of a JSON string), so you're trying to parse `"[objectObject]"`

Comment: JSON.parse takes a string and spits out an object. You already have your object, just use it with `data[0]`.

Comment: You mean `JSON.parse(data[0]);`?

Comment: And you have an unexpected `[`.

Comment: Because this is not JSON, but an ordinary JavaScript object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parseZ) `JSON.parse()` takes a `string` as an argument.

In your example, you're passing an object -- which is why you get an error.

In fact, `JSON.parse()` returns an object, so passing an object to it is utterly pointless.

Comment: "utterly pointless" is over-restrictive to all potentials. if the object has a custom `toString()` or `toJSON()` (OP doesn't) that emitted JSON, then `JSON.parse(theObject)` could work, but that's not the majority of cases, so it's merely  "mostly pointless"

Answer (score 1):

The JSON object's parse function expects a String.

You can convert a JSON object to a String and then parse it.

```
var data = [{
  "name":"john doe",
  "birth":"09/07/15"
},
{
  "name":"jane doe",
  "birth":"09/07/15"
}];

var object = JSON.stringify(data[0]);
JSON.parse(object);
```